# Javascript : getElementById is null, don't understand what's wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm facing this problem with javascript. I updated my design by rebulding my html and since them, my script for this part doesn't work. I' tried to look at other post on stackoverflow but i don't manage to correct my problem.

I would like to understand what's wrong with my code !

Here it is :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content%}
{% for post in dict_post %}  

    <!-- PHOTO / ADRESSE / VENDEURS-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pav flex-wrap">
            <div class="photo d-flex" onclick="location.href='{{ post.8 }}'">
            </div>

            <div class="adresse d-flex" id="address">
                <a class="adressetext" onclick="change_text()" >Obtenir l'adresse</a>
                <div id="form_address" style="display:none">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                         {% csrf_token %} 
                         {{ form }}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vendeurs d-flex flex-wrap">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  

<script>
    function change_text(){
        var address = "{{ post.6 }}";
        if (address != "Inconnue pour le moment"){
            address = address.split(' ').join("+")
            var google_address = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + address
            console.log(google_address)
            document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = "<p class=\"addressfounded\"> {{ post.6 }} </p>" +
                                                            "<a href=" + google_address + "> <p class=\" googlemapslink\"> Ouvrir sur Google maps </p> </a>" ;                                                   
        } else {
            document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = "<p class=\"unknowaddress\"> L'adresse est inconnue Voulez-vous la rajouter ? </p>" +
                                                             "<a class=\"addaddress\" onclick=\"form_add_address()\" > Ajouter l'adresse </a>" ;
        }
    }

    function form_add_address(){
        var displayed = document.getElementById("form_address").style.display;
        if(displayed == "none"){
            document.getElementById("form_address").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script> 
{% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

I'm facing this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    form_add_address http://0.0.0.0:9999/nb_database/05eafb35-74ca-53f1-b2e6-81c2ca97b0ee/:117
    onclick http://0.0.0.0:9999/nb_database/05eafb35-74ca-53f1-b2e6-81c2ca97b0ee/:1
```

Comment: When you set `innerHTML`, you're replacing everything within the parent element

Comment: Generating global variables (like `change_text` and `form_add_address`) in a loop seems like a mistake.

Comment: Ok, thank's guy i see where is my mistake and why ! @Quentin , could you give me an advice to have a better practice ? Thank's

Comment: Write functions once. Bind them with `addEventListener`, not `onclick` attributes. Store data in `data-*` attributes not embedded in duplicate functions. Make use of the event object to determine which element triggered the call to the function. Use `button` elements to create a clickable element to run JS (don't use links for that).